# how to get all wordpress categories ids and print into html attribute

Tags: php, wordpress

how to get all wordpress categories id and print into my specific html attribute?

```
ie: <a href="#" id="1,2,3,4,5,6">menu</a>
```

in this example in id="1,2,3,4,5,6...." here i want to print all wordpress categories ids.

is that possible ?

here is example code for retrieve all categories ids :

```
<?php
$category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
foreach($category_ids as $cat_id) {
$cat_name = get_cat_name($cat_id);
echo $cat_id . ',';
}
?>
```

but i don't able to print into my HTML attribute...

please help

thank you.

Comment: The strange question: Why did you do that?

Comment: because i need only categories ids to pass categories ids through my custom jquery code for my front-end html display :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try implode() function for converting the array of ids into string.

Just like this:

```
<?php $category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
//sort($category_ids);  //If required in asc order
$ids = implode(",", $category_ids); ?>
```

OR

If you want to remove Uncategorized id "1", then use sort() function for sorting array in asc order & then use array_shift() function for removing the first element of array .i.e. Uncategorized id "1".

```
<?php $category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
    sort($category_ids);
    $removed_id = array_shift($category_ids);
    $ids = implode(",", $category_ids); ?>
```

Now, place this $ids variable into your  tag.

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $ids ; ?>">menu</a>
```

Hope, this may be helpful to you.

Comment: how to exclude Uncategorized id "1" in above code ?

Comment: yes i got your solution and it is working perfectly thank you. can you please tell me how to exclude Uncategorized id "1" in your above code ?

Comment: First of all i have sorted the array element in ascending order, so the uncategorized id "1" comes on the first place. Then, i use array_shift() function for removing the first element of array, & then our array $category_ids contains no Uncategorized id "1", & then we converted the array into string.

Comment: perfect , thank you. code working 100%. thank you once again.